# Depends: postgresql-client-10 but it is not going to be installed on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to install Postgres 10 on ubuntu 17.04 but i am getting this error

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-10 : Depends: postgresql-client-10 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libpq5 (>= 9.3~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: sysstat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The thing is I've googled it and only found a few, the only solution that i got is to upgrade my ubuntu which i don't have the permission to do.

Is there any way to get around this issue?

Comment: You've not given anywhere near enough information to help you here. (1) What sources are you using for postgresql? (2) What sources have you set up for the rest of the system (3) What packages are held, why and which ones are broken?

Comment: 17.04 is EOL'ed so mainstream providers won't produce any package for it. It's not even in the list at https://packages.ubuntu.com.